# Does Hibernate using preparedStatement internally when native update query?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jdbc, native-sql

I have a question.

Does the JPA(Hibernate) use a preparedStatement internally when using native update query?

```
Query query = EntityManager.createNativeQuery(updateSql);

//... some other codes here

query.setParameter(1, "column1");
query.setParameter(2, "column2");

query.executeUpdate();
```

Does the updateSql pre-compiled?

Comment: Yes, JPA engines use prepared statements.

Comment: I've dug into Hibernate codes, but I couldn't find the part of making preparedStatement. Could anyone tell me how we can convince that?

Comment: Just enable SQL logging, and you'll see the SQL, with the `?` placeholders.

Comment: I think [here](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm) you can find proof.

Comment: https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/e5dc635a52362f69b69acb8d5b166b69b165dbbd/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/engine/jdbc/spi/StatementPreparer.java

Comment: thx guys. But I still couldn't find the related some codes with executeUpdate and StatementPrepare. Does the "?" placeholder can be proof of pre-compiled SQL?